# Remove background color of MaterialButton and set icon

Tags: android, material-components-android, materialbutton

I wanted to remove the color background of a Material Button and I wanted to show an icon only. The icon shouldn't be tinted with any color but should display the picture(drawable) I am setting. Here is what I want to achieve:
[image]

The Button attributes I am using is:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_google"
                        app:iconPadding="0dp"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:minHeight="48dp"
                        android:insetTop="0dp"
                        android:insetBottom="0dp"
                        app:elevation="3dp"
                        android:minWidth="48dp"
                        app:iconGravity="textStart"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:cornerRadius="50dp"
                        app:icon="@drawable/ic_google_logo"/>
```

And this is what I am getting:
[image]

While I was setting an icon of transparent color of google logo like this(`ic_google_logo`):
[image]

I have tried to add this style on the button:
`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"`
and it will tint the icon while correcting the background color. like this:

[image]

If you have come across this issue before please help. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why don't use basic `ImageView` with `android:src="@drawable/ic_google_logo"`? Corner radius can be done with another solution.

Comment: MaterialButton applies some tinting by default but you could try with `app:backgroundTint="@color/white"` and `app:iconTint="@android:color/transparent"`?

Comment: @RobCo it tinted my icon white.. now everything is white.

Comment: @lbasek the matrial buttons have so many great feature already and I wanted to use that. But there also some head-aches like this. :/

Comment: If you set `app:backgroundTint="@null"` you can use `android:background` again

Answer (score 2):

Add following property :

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

Full Code :

> ```
> <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
>     android:id="@+id/btn_google"
>     android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
>     app:iconPadding="0dp"
>     android:padding="0dp"
>     android:minHeight="48dp"
>     android:insetTop="0dp"
>     android:insetBottom="0dp"
>     app:elevation="3dp"
>     android:minWidth="48dp"
>     app:iconGravity="textStart"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     app:cornerRadius="50dp"
>     app:icon="@drawable/ic_google_logo"/>
> ```

Read following document to know details about the attributes of Material Button:

https://material.io/components/buttons/android#text-button